# Cannot connect to Kubernetes Dashboard as non-admin user with kubectl proxy

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-dashboard

I want to allow non-admin users to use the Kubernetes Dashboard to view the K8 objects in their namespaces.  As cluster-admin, I have no issues connecting the the Kubernetes Dashboard using kubectl proxy.  When I first attempted to access it with an application service account with read-only access to their entire namespace, I received the error below:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "services \"https:kubernetes-dashboard:\" is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:ops-jenkins-lab:k8-dashboard-ops-jenkins-lab\" cannot get resource \"services/proxy\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"kubernetes-dashboard\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "name": "https:kubernetes-dashboard:",
    "kind": "services"
  },
  "code": 403
}
```

I added additional RBAC roles to allow the application service account access to services and services/proxy in the kubernetes-dashboard namespace.  Now I get the following error:

```
Forbidden (403): Http failure response for http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/api/v1/login: 403 Forbidden
```

If I create an ingress for the dashboard I can connect without out issue to the Kubernetes Dashboard using the same application service account and have access to view all the kubernetes objects within the namespace (once I switch from default to the correct namespace).  I'd actually prefer to use the ingress but for some reason once I connect to the Kubernetes Dashboard via a browser it hijacks the ingress for all my other applications.  No matter which ingress I try to connect to it automatically redirects me to the Kubernetes Dashboard.  I have to clear all browser data to connect to other applications.

RBAC clusterrole and rolebinding:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  annotations:
  name: k8-dashboard
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - extensions
  - apps
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - batch
  resources:
  - jobs
  - cronjobs
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - autoscaling
  resources:
  - horizontalpodautoscalers
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - policy
  resources:
  - poddisruptionbudgets
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - '*'
  resources:
  - persistentvolumeclaims
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - '*'
  resources:
  - services
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - '*'
  resources:
  - events
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - '*'
  resources:
  - configmaps
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - apps
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - patch
- apiGroups:
  - apps
  resources:
  - deployments/scale
  verbs:
  - update
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods/attach
  - pods/exec
  - pods/log
  - pods/status
  - pods/delete
  verbs:
  - '*'
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - delete
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - secrets
  verbs:
  - create
  - get
  - delete
  - patch
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  annotations:
  labels:
    subjectName: k8-dashboard-sa
  name: k8-dashboard-ops-jenkins-lab
  namespace: ops-jenkins-lab
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: k8-dashboard
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: k8-dashboard-ops-jenkins-lab
  namespace: ops-jenkins-lab
```

So this leaves me with needing to connect to the Kubernetes Dashboard using kubectl proxy.  I'm certain there's additional RBAC required when using kubectl proxy as a non-admin user; however, I have yet to figure it out.  Any suggests?

Comment: Please add RBAC role and rolebinding associated with `system:serviceaccount:ops-jenkins-lab:k8-dashboard-ops-jenkins-lab` service account to your question.

Comment: @HelloWorld I added the RBAC clusterrole and rolebinding.

Answer (score 0):

Your ClusterRole is associated with RoleBinding, and [in documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-example) you can read:

> A RoleBinding can also reference a ClusterRole to grant the
>   permissions defined in that ClusterRole to resources inside the
>   RoleBinding’s namespace

This means that even though you are using ClusterRole, the permisions are limited to one namespace, which is `ops-jenkins-lab` in your case.

And a long as the dashboard you are trying to access is in `kubernetes-dashboard` namespace you won't be able to do it beacause your RoleBinding is in wrong namespace.

To allow `k8-dashboard-ops-jenkins-lab` serviceAccount to access resources in different namespace you should either create ClusterRoleBinding (clusterrolebindings are not namespaced) or (better option) RoleBinding in namespace you want to access (in your case that would be `kubernetes-dashboard` namespace).

Let me know if something needs more clarification.